# powershell hashtable using key named length

Tags: powershell, key, hashtable

I'm got a problem parsing a file with key value pairs when one of the keys is named "length". Piping the content to ConvertFrom-StringData creates a hashtable with the key called "length" but, when I try to access it, I get the length of the table instead. Turns out this is because ConvertFrom-StringData is returning an array of hashtables and Length is the length of the array (6 in this case).

Any idea how to get around this? For a regular hashtable you can create a key called length and access it just fine ($tmp[1].length gives 1000um as it should). I won't usually know the index of the "length" field in the file, however.

```
> $tmp = Get-Content "Sample Settings.txt"

> $tmp
device=Hall bar
length=1000um
width=500um
thickness=8nm
system=PPMS
field=Perpendicular

> $tmp = $tmp | ConvertFrom-StringData

> $tmp

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                            
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                            
device                         Hall bar                                                                                                                                                                                         
length                         1000um                                                                                                                                                                                           
width                          500um                                                                                                                                                                                            
thickness                      8nm                                                                                                                                                                                              
system                         PPMS                                                                                                                                                                                             
field                          Perpendicular                                                                                                                                                                                    

> $tmp.length
6

> $tmp[1].length
1000um

> $tmp.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                             
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                             
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

> $tmp[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                             
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                             
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

Comment: the contents of your txt file might be useful.  since $tmp is an array, you should treat it as such.  array indexing, foreach, etc.

Comment: The output from the Get-Content command at the top is what it looks like.

Comment: Apologies for that oversight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get *regular* hashtable, use `-Raw` switch as follows:

```
$tmp = Get-Content "Sample Settings.txt" -Raw | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

Then:

```
$tmp
<#
Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
device                         Hall bar                                        
thickness                      8nm                                             
field                          Perpendicular                                   
width                          500um                                           
system                         PPMS                                            
length                         1000um                                          
<##>

$tmp.gettype().Name
# Hashtable

$tmp.Count
# 6

$tmp.length
# 1000um
```

Comment: Brilliant. I knew there had to be an easy way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `IndexOf()` to get the index and then use it to get the value:

```
$li = $tmp.keys.IndexOf('length')
$tmp[$li].length
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-replace` with a RegEx to prepend `length` with a string (here `my`):

```
> $tmp = $tmp -replace '^(?=length)','my' | convertfrom-stringdata
> $tmp
Name                           Value
----                           -----
device                         Hall bar
mylength                       1000um
width                          500um
thickness                      8nm
system                         PPMS
field                          Perpendicular

> $tmp.mylength
1000um
```

`(?=..)` is a [zero length look ahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)